# Identifying an old French movie about poor parents' infant adopted by a rich family

Tags: cinéma

I would like to identify an old French movie about an infant born into a very poor family. The child is adopted by a rich, childless family and grows up in a well-to-do environment. Many years later, as a young man, he returns to the village where he was born and is rather disgusted with his origins. I do not remember what else happens in the movie. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You may find something here : https://www.agence-adoption.fr/mediatheque-2/filmographie-sur-ladoption/

Comment: This belongs on movies.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Circeus Why was this question closed and not migrated to movies.se ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat If I understand well, this question was first asked on movies, closed, asked here, closed here, migrated to movies and finally this migration was rejected by movies ! Before migrate a question, we should pay attention it respects rules on the other site, when we can of course

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I'm not a mod, I wouldn't know. It would still be irrelevant to this site as it is not a question about the French Language.

Answer (score 1):

La vie est un long fleuve tranquille ?

Comment: I agree that the description fits, however I am fairly sure that the action of the movie I'm looking for takes place either in the 19th c. or early in the 20th c.